# android listview cachecolorhint transparent

Tags: android, listview

I've made a `ListView` with multiple item types, each having a different background color. I'm using the `android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent` attribute, but it's always showing white color and not the color of the bottom-most/top-most row.

Answer (score 0):

you might have to set this attribute onto your `ListView` as well:

`android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"`